# A Google Docs document picker?

Tags: php, javascript, google-api, google-docs

Working on a method to allow users to "attach" a doc from their Google account to an object in my application. Really, all I need to do is create a link in my app to their asset in Google Docs.
Some sort of document chooser that allows users to browse their docs would be very helpful.

Is there a standard method/interface to accomplish this? Something similar to embedding a doc in a Google Site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official API

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

Comment: Yes, the list API is useful and fairly simple but I'm thinking more of the interface.

Comment: The answer below from benmcdonald is exactly what you are looking for